# Grails css problem

Tags: css, grails

I'm developing a Grails app and I need to modify some elements' style. I tried to add a css class to the main.css file but it is not working.

In /web-app/css/main.css:

```
.artistItem {
   background-color: #444;
   border: 1px solid #fff;
   padding: 10px;
   color: #ccc;
   width: 200px;
}
```

In the .gsp:

```
<div class="artistItem">Some text</div>
```

But the div remains unchanged. Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.artistItem {
   background-color: #444 !important;
   border: 1px solid #fff !important;
   padding: 10px !important;
   color: #ccc !important;
   width: 200px !important;
}
```

If that works, then you know there is another css stylesheet overriding it. If not the css is not being included properly.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! I have to check what's overriding it.

Comment: No problem. as michael said, use firebug to check what styles ARE being used, makes life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

**This isn't a direct answer**

Playing around with CSS in grails can be a little frustrating for someone that hasn't had a lot of exposure to CSS in general (I'm speaking form experience).  Grails provides a nice clean CSS for a good starting point but trying to build on it without understanding CSS can cause some pain.

I would recommend looking at a couple tools like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox or [Chrome's built in developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html#access), IE also has a nice [developer tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359).  These tools allow you to see how the browser is rendering your page and what CSS elements are being used or not used.  They also expose the javascript console and several other nice debugging tools.  I believe this are essential tools to help understand what the browser is doing.

I hope this helps!